# Turn on/off AWS EMR clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

How can I turn on/off EMR clusters? There is only one possibility to terminate permanently. What if I do not need the cluster at nights and I do not want to create a new cluster every morning?

Comment: Create, Use, Terminate, Create, Use, Terminate, Create, Use, Terminate, ... there is no way to pause / suspend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Stopping an EMR cluster is not supported. You simply terminate it when you don't need it.

To protect your data, you should be using [EMRFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-fs.html) which allows EMR cluster to read data from S3. This way, there is no need to copy any data from S3 to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable scale up\scale down policies available in EMR UI and resize your cluster based on multiple metrics, i.e. ram\cpu utilization. You can also create external job that will send to EMR scale up\scale down command via awscli and you can schedule such jobs to run in the morning and in the evening.
From my experience resizing works well on task nodes while resizing core nodes demands  HDFS sync that works only if you don't run any tasks on your EMR.